# Increase image saturation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How would I go about increasing the saturation of an [RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) image in MATLAB? Would I have to convert the RGB array to an [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) array first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest way would certainly be to [convert to HSV color space](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rgb2hsv.html), increase the saturation value as you like, then [convert it back to an RGB image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hsv2rgb.html):

```
hsvImage = rgb2hsv(rgbImage);  %# Convert the image to HSV space
hsvImage(:,:,2) = 1;           %# Maximize the saturation
rgbImage = hsv2rgb(hsvImage);  %# Convert the image back to RGB space
```

Comment: Hmm setting it at 1 left me with lots of random red patches (too much saturation I think) so I've instead multiplied it to saturate all areas a bit less and so that they are all saturated by the same amount eg. `hsvImage(:,:,2) = hsvImage(:,:,2)*1.5`. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @Phoen1xUK: I was just using that as an example for modifying the saturation plane, since I didn't know specifically what sort of increase you wanted to apply. The red patches you saw in your HSV image were likely white or gray areas in your RGB image (with equal amounts of red, green, and blue). When converted to HSV, neutral colors like this are often assigned a default hue of 0 (i.e. red). When the saturation is increased from 0 to 1, this default hue becomes noticeable.